# object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exception

I've started getting the following exception while debugging a 32bit MFC C++ app under VS2010 SP1, Windows 7 64.  While I can easily ignore it, I'm just wondering what it is.

> First-chance exception at 0x751eb9bc in SCCW.exe: 0x80010108: The
>   object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661005/error-the-object-invoked-has-disconnected-from-its-clients-automate-ie-8-wit) and a [google search](http://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&gs_nf=1&pq=0x751eb9bc&cp=52&gs_id=f&xhr=t&q=The%20object%20invoked%20has%20disconnected%20from%20its%20clients&pf=p&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&oq=The%20object%20invoked%20has%20disconnected%20from%20its%20clients&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=ca91e5c879985e65&ion=1&biw=1280&bih=899) suggest its automation related, and while my app supports automation, it isn't doing anything automation related at the time.  The stack frame for the active thread does not show anything much, all system DLLS (ntdll.dll,rpcrt4.dll,ole32.dll).  I've been debugging the same app on the same system for a long time and only started seeing this recent, so just wondering why.  Any ideas, and can it be safely ignored?

Comment: Okay, that's not real C++, I can't help you with MS stuff. But usually the first-chance exception doesn't affect the program

Comment: @Geoffroy if you really cannot help anyone because he/she uses the MS compiler, your knowledge of C++ is really lacking as there's only a minor number of non-standard features, let alone they influence the matter asked about in this question

Comment: Can you share the stacktraces *with symbols loaded*?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx  Yep, it is very MS specific and completely unrelated to the C++ language.

Comment: @Mahmoud Al-Qudsi, symbols are present for my app, MFC, and C runtimes.  Not sure how to go about loading any other symbols, e.g. for ntdll.dll

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe and here's one for C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716363/first-chance-exception-long-at-memory-location I even suspect if you compile a C++ app using the GNU toolset and run it under the MS debugger it behaves the same..

Comment: @Shane actually, the symbols for your app would be icing on the cake, the MS symbols are what really matter.

Comment: I have an MFC C++ Win32 Microsoft Word Addin DLL that is getting the same hResult error. This code has been stable for at least 4 years, but now returns this error if I let it sit for only about a minute or two. The problems is not C++ since the code hasn't changed. 
Something has changed on Microsoft's side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be some other executable that gets loaded in.  It could be something that has windows hooks etc such as a virus scanner, or it could be a shell extension.  Look up what SCCW is.  If it is something you don't need on your system, uninstall it.

It should be safe to ignore, and you can prevent the application from stopping in the debugger by adding the exception type and telling VS not to stop on it.

Debug | Exceptions...

Then under Win32 Exceptions untick "80010108 Server Disconnected from clients".

Comment: SCCW is the application I'm debugging, and yes I've disabled the specific exceptions from being passed on to the debugger.  Funny thing is the same exception `The object invoked has disconnected from its clients` has come back under a number of different numbers.